# Best Practices for large Flex apps?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm in the middle of creating a fairly large flex application, and over time, it's started to edge toward unmaintainability.

I'm using 3 external library projects which are still small enough to remain maintainable and reusable, but the main project seems to be impossible to keep organized.

Part of the problem seems to be that I have about 30 objects inheriting from a single abstract superclass type object.  All of child objects have both a logic component and a ui component which are tightly integrated to each other.  The superclass object has about 60 shared methods and properties, most of which can be overridden in any of the child classes, a few of which should be overridden in all child classes.

To add to the complexity, these have to communicate between themselves, and this is usually via the container object they reside in.  Additionally, the main project has to create value objects out of these so they can be sent to a FlourineFX backend for storage, and additional authentication/authorization logic.

I've created much larger projects in languages from old MS BASIC (pre VB), Ada, VB (3 to .Net 1), C++, and C# without this problem. (well, old VB tended toward this problem because of the same tight integration between UI and logic) So, is there any thing I'm missing, or is there any best practices that I can implement? (even if that means rewriting entire swaths of code)

And yes, this may be an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96040/flex-best-practices) conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use any framework implementations in this project?  A framework would help modularise a lot of this complexity and hopefully remove a lot of the dependencies you seem to have between the application logic and views.

I'm a massive advocate of the [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/) framework which implements the mvcs pattern and offers dependency injection for use throughout your project.  There are others out there such as [pureMvc](http://puremvc.org/), [Cairngorm](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm), [Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/).  Have a look around and see which best suits your project.

It sounds to me like you really need to do a big refactor which is a risky process in such a large project. It could be well worth it if you're struggling to maintain it.  If you are going to refactor definitely refactor into a framework. It's probably the area that will give you most bang for your buck (pound for the brits ;) )

Comment: FWIW, we use pureMVC for some parts of our application suite, and I believe it adds a lot of unnecessary complexity and indirection. The parts that don't use a framework seem easier to build, easier to maintain. And this is a big SaaS suite with lots of apps and modules within the apps. YMMV.

Comment: I'm not a massive fan of PureMvc myself either but mainly down to it's testability.  RobotLegs is much more apt to being unit tested.  Having worked on large projects both with and without frameworks I definitely see the benefits of using them though, especially when they are going to be maintained in the future.  Any projects my department works on now all subscribe to some sort of framework so we have a standard implementation that makes it easier to jump from one project to another.

Comment: I'm not actually using a framework, and after looking into this, it may be a good chunk of the solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

James Hay's conversation starter is a good one, but for HUGE applications I would take time to test and consider memory management for some of the suggestions in that answer/conversation.  RobotLegs is great and all, but I would worry about 'over-singletonization' and potential memory management issues that it would create (though I have to admit that I've never used and avoided robotLegs because of it's use of singletons).
If you were thinking IoC and dependency injection (like that which robotLegs provides), I'd suggest a look at swiz -- I really like the new 'instance-direction' swiz has taken.  My only issue with it (in the current beta) is they have some cleanup issues, though these issues are easy enough to remedy (look through their source and any time you completely remove a component from the stage you'll have to play the profiling game and make sure everything is getting cleaned up --- we had to create temp functions to remove the changewatchers and destroy 'display list bean instances' until they get that stuff fixed).

The project I lead had many of the potential issues you must be worried about.  Our ERP app has thousands of modules and the thing is running on client machines for hours/days at a time, constantly loading and unloading modules.  Garbage collection and memory management were and is THE issues.

As for using mate, the annoying carhorn, or pureMVC, we created our own framework two years ago.  It borrowed ideas from cairngorm, but overall my suggestion is to use whatever you can quickly learn, understand and teach while thinking about garbage collection.  Our internal Model and View classes now use swiz (for newly developed modules) and this has made maintainability and code readability super smooth.

I hope my blabbing has helped at least a bit.
Best of luck.

Comment: @jeremy.mooer - RobotLegs doesn't actually use singletons so the 'over-singltonization' point is actually incorrect. It's actually extremely unit testable, much more so than Pmvc.

Comment: @James Hay- yeah, like I said, never used it so danka for clarifying.  I should probably download the source again sometime.  I would absoultely use plain ol' classes for models/controllers with an openFlux-like or flex4-like architecture + robotLegs over Carhorn, pmvc or mate.  I've always been surprised that one of the major flex consulting firms always uses pureMVC for ground-up contracts. I guess if your target 'user usage time' is LT an hour.. which is probably pretty typical. Regardless, I'd much rather support something that doesn't require 10+ files for a simple view than otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need a clean separation of UI and domain components. Look into the [component guidelines](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) and the [Presentation Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/) discussed by Martin Fowler, especially the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

To bring these pieces together, you might want to use an IoC container like [Spring ActionScript](http://www.springactionscript.org/). This is a non-intrusive framework that allows you to keep layers separated.

Don't let a framework get in your way. I've seen massive misuse of frameworks like PureMVC and Cairngorm mainly because apply them in an all-or-nothing fashion.